# How can I set a select option value without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert a jQuery code into pure Javascript

```
$('.city option[value="NY"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

How can I do it? I am trying the following code but it gives me an error

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.city option[value="NY"]')
    .setAttribute('selected','selected');
```

Error:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName(...).setAttribute is not a function
```

html:

```
 <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control">
    <option value="77">29 Palms</option>
    <option value="183">Acton</option>
    <option value="270">Adelanto</option>
    <option value="348">Agoura Hills</option>
    <option value="353">Agua Dulce</option>
    <option value="360">Aguanga</option>
    <option value="372">Ahwahnee</option>
    <option value="622">Alhambra</option></select>
```

Comment: A couple problems with the HTML.. the select element doesn't have a class of `city`, and there aren't any `option` elements with a value of `NY`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: IE8+ only

Use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByClassName) as you are trying to find an element with a class and attribute selectors

```
var els = document.querySelector('.city option[value="NY"]');
if(els){
    els.setAttribute('selected','selected');
    //or els.selected = true;
}
```

[getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByClassName) takes a class name as the argument, not a complex selector like the one you have used, also it returns an array of dom elements, so you need to iterate through the array contents and then set its property

---

```
var els = document.querySelector('select[name="city"] option[value="360"]');
if(els){
    els.selected = true;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3d9r2/)

Comment: i tried both. they both dont give any error neither they set the attribute

Comment: @user2535089 It works **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/n3mNx/)** maybe the HTML structure is wrong?

Comment: @user2535089 please share your html

Comment: i am trying like this   var els = document.querySelector('.city option[value="<?= $user->city?>"]');
    if(els){
        els.setAttribute('selected','selected');
        //or els.selected = true;
    }

Comment: html is  <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control">
        <option value="77">29 Palms</option>
        <option value="183">Acton</option>
        <option value="270">Adelanto</option>
        <option value="348">Agoura Hills</option>
        <option value="353">Agua Dulce</option>
        <option value="360">Aguanga</option>
        <option value="372">Ahwahnee</option>
        <option value="622">Alhambra</option></select>

Comment: @user2535089 your markup select does not have a class city try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3d9r2/1/

Comment: @user2535089 also there is no option with value `NY`

Comment: Thank You now its working fine with your last edit. Thank You again

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var cities = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
    var options = this.getElementsByTagName("option");
    for (var i2 = 0; i < options.length; i2++){
        if (this.value == "NY"){
            this.setAttribute("selected", "selected")      
        }
    }
}
```